# Accessing transaction context in a Postgres trigger

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have a `Postgres 11.3` database that has lots of triggers on it.  These triggers are automatically generated through some metaprogramming via `SQLAlchemy`, and essentially wrap every `CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE` action on every record, storing a "version" of it.  This process is entirely automatic and requires no effort from the end user.

I'd like to be able to add a `user_id` foreign key to my `versions` table.  This is `user_id` as in application user, **not** the connected postgres/system within which the transaction is executing.  This field will need to be provided by the application calling method.

My initial attempt has involved automating out a set of stored procedures/postgres functions for each table.  This works, but I can't figure out a way to access the *context* from the current transaction.  Here is some psuedo code to demonstrate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_address(resource_id INTEGER, user_id INTEGER)
    RETURNS INTEGER as
    $BODY$
        DECLARE
            context USER_ID INTEGER; // something like this magical context keyword
        BEGIN
            USER_ID = user_id;

            DELETE FROM address WHERE id = resource_id;

            RETURN 1;
        END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In the `DELETE` trigger for this table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_address_history_on_delete()
    RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE "versions"
        SET 
          date_archived = now()::timestamp,
          user_id = context USER_ID  // theres that magical context keyword again
        WHERE
            resource_id = OLD.id;
        RETURN OLD;
    END
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

You will see in this hypothetical I'm trying to access what would essentially be a lexically scoped/closure value, sitting in the context of a single transaction.

Is this possible, or is there another way I can go about something like this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a transaction-local [custom configuration variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html).

Assign the variable in your `delete_address()` function with:

```
PERFORM set_config('my_vars.user_id', user_id, true);
```

...and retrieve the value in your trigger using:

```
current_setting('my_vars.user_id')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this.  For anyone looking at how to specify it to transaction-specific, here we go: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-admin.html  .  Note that it needs to period "." delimited, so "exciting.variable" will work, but "excitingvariable" wont